# Why 8bytes plaintext becomes 16bytes Cipher?

Tags: c#, tripledes

Its a very simple code. But what I don't understand, When the `Blocksize` is 8byte, Cipher size is 16bytes, why? I am expecting it to be same as the `Blocksize`. From simple thinking, I give 64bits as plaintext and expect to have 64bits as cipher. And I really don't see any reason to do any padding here. It seems that after every 8bytes(`Blocksize`) the Cipher becomes 8bytes more. 16bytes Block becomes 24bytes Cipher etc. Why is it like this? I really want to know.

And just for curiosity, is there any possibility/way to have 8bytes Cipher from 8bytes Block?

**The 3DES code:** (only encryption part)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Plain Text: ");
        string original =Console.ReadLine();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider myTripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original,myTripleDES.Key, myTripleDES.IV);
        string encrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted,myTripleDES.Key, myTripleDES.IV);
        Console.WriteLine("encryted: " +encrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("decrypted: " +decrypted);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }



    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        byte [] data= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        Console.WriteLine("The Block length: " +data.Length);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdsAlg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdsAlg.BlockSize = 64;
        tdsAlg.KeySize = 128;
        tdsAlg.Key = Key;  
        tdsAlg.IV = IV;  
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = tdsAlg.CreateEncryptor(tdsAlg.Key, tdsAlg.IV);
        byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("The Cipher length: " + encrypted.Length);
        return encrypted;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default padding mode for `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` in .NET is PKCS7. PKCS7 padding mode adds as many bytes as needed to fill the block, but always at least one byte(!). This means that if your data ends in a block boundary, another block needs to be added that consists solely of padding bytes.

You can avoid this by explicitly setting:

```
tdsAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

You will set that now your cipher length will be 8 bytes as expected.

As for the reason why padding is needed even though your data matches the block size:

Imagine that your data ends with bytes that look like valid padding bytes. In this case the decryptor of your message would assume that these are in fact padding bytes and your message would be shorten. To avoid this, there is at least one padding byte added in all cases. The padding bytes in PKCS7 actually state the number of bytes in the padding. So if the padded message ends in 0x07 it means 7 padding bytes were used and they can be removed when decoding the message.

Comment: Problem solved :) and thank you so much. Now everything is clear to me.

Comment: "Imagine that your data ends with bytes that look like valid padding bytes. In this case the decryptor of your message would assume that these are in fact padding bytes and your message would be shorten." ---can I avoid this by setting the decryptor's padding mode to "None" as well?

Comment: Both the sender and the receiver have to agree on the padding mode. In your case this means that the Decrypt method also has to set PaddingMode.None

Comment: Thanks. Will this work on AES too? I mean, does the padding mode (PKCS7) of AESCryptoServiceProvider works same as this?